# Computing the indefinite integral of a non-rationalized fraction

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Compute the indefinite integral
$$\int \frac{x-1} {1 + \sqrt{x^2+2x-3}}dx$$

What do I need to do then? Fraction isn't simplified.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is the integral? Because its primitive looks like a nightmare.

Comment: One thought is that if $u=x^2+2x-3$ then $\dfrac{du} 2 = (x+1)\,dx$ and you can write $$ \int \frac{x-1}{\cdots\cdots} \, dx = \int \frac{x+1}{\cdots\cdots}\,dx + \int \frac{-2}{\cdots\cdots}\,dx $$and then use the substitution in the first integral. That still leaves the second integral to be done differently.  But of course you instantly think of completing the square: $x^2+2x-3 = (x+1)^2 - 4$ and then you can write $x+1 = 2\sec\theta$ and $dx = 2\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$.  I'm not sure where this goes after that; otherwise I'd post an answer. $\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$Possibly skipping that first step and going straight to the substitution is better. $\qquad$

Comment: Do not repost your questions. Edit the original.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Use substitution: to eliminate the radical from
$$\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}=\sqrt{(x+1)^2-4}$$
set $x+1=2\cosh t,\enspace t\ge 0$, $\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=2\sinh t\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu t$. You'll obtain
$$\int\frac{2(\cosh t-1)}{1+2\sinh t}2\sinh t\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu t$$
Then transform into a rational function of $u=\mathrm e^t$, which is standard.

Comment: Nice substitution, yet I still can't see it so "standard" or even straighforward with the rational function substitution. Perhaps later, after the asker gives a thought, you can please extend on this?

Comment: Not straightforward but rational functions of exponential are indeed standard — mean what has to be done is known. It's part of those integrals which reduce to an integral of a rational function by a convenient substitution.